# Annoying Popup - (or other more graceful solution)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here's my "need" - I have a user opening a window with a document displayed, I need to log the amount of time the user has that window "in focus" or "opened"... IF the user views another window, I want to stop logging the time - and resume logging if they re-focus on that page... basically I want to "know" how long it took a user to read the page.

this is a review type scenario, where the users is a 'trusted' member who needs to log their time... I want to keep a 'running total' for reference only - so if the user says that spent 10 min, on the page, but my log shows the window was only open for 2min, I know I've got a problem...either with my code or my people.. ;)

My thought was to keep a js counter going when the page was in focus, pause on blur or on close, and Ajax the data back to my db... and add any subsequent time to that record if the user returns...

onUnload doesn't seem to work, at least when i try - plus it doesn't catch a closing of the browser... so I was thinking I could launch a NEW window, when the document window is closed (not to be annoying - but to make the logging call to the server, and then close itself).

Does anyone have a solution for this? I know this all smacks of 'poor' design, but if someone has a 'correct' way to handle this scenario - please tell me. (BTW- IE is a requirement- it's intranet based IE7 req.) 
Thx

======== sample code below - that is 'not' working...kinda ============
When i say it's NOT working, this is what I mean... The "XMLHttpRequest" Is being made, i assume because the response is the message I'd expect - HOWEVER the log isn't changes (I know you'll say it's the php page, but if I call the url directly - it works fine... so it's no the logging page, IN ADDITION the 60 second setInterval() seems to fire randomly, because my response alert just pops up, sometime 10 in a row with no time between, certainly not at 'regular' 60 sec intervals... THOUGHTS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var closeMe = 0;
var logMe = 0;

//the window doesn't have focus, do nothing or something that let's them know we're not logging at the moment
function onBlur() {
    //after 2 min of non focus, close it.
    closeMe = setInterval('window.close()',120000); //after 2 min of non focus, close it.
};

//the window has focus... keep logging.
function onFocus(){
    //stop the close counter - in the event to 'blurred' sometime
    clearInterval ( closeMe );  
    //run the AJAX on a schedule - we're doing it every minute - bu tyou can do it as often as you like
    logMe = setInterval('logTime()',60000);
};

//call a script that logs another minute...
function logTime() {
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "ajax-on-time-interval.php", false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
    alert(serverResponse); 
}

// check for Internet Explorer... IE uses 'onfocusin/out" - everything else uses "onfocus/blur"
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Here's a partial example of BOTH things I'm trying to do... 

https://applynowdc1.chase.com/FlexAppWeb/renderApp.do?CELL=6RQW&MSC=S02&PROMO=DF01&SPID=CSJN

This page launches a 'please don't leave' type of div when you mouse outside of the page, AND is has a timeout feature, so it's running a counter... I've tried to scour the code to glean my solution - no luck...

Comment: `window` does not have a `focus` event...

Comment: You can edit your original post and add it there.

Comment: @elusive - It wouldn't be a focus event it would be an onfocus event. You may still be right, but the reason, i think, that there is not a focus event for the window element is to avoid malicious intent.

Answer (score 3):

I've have thought that a regular Ajax based "heartbeat" that updates the underlying database data every 'n' seconds (depending on the granularity you require, I'd have thought every minute would be sufficient) would be a neater solution than a pop-up and also avoid the fact that not all browsers handle onunload, etc. gracefully.

That said, I'm presuming that JavaScript will be enabled on these machines. (Seems fair based on your question.)

Comment: @Anthony - Yup. Just like a real heart it'll sometimes stop if the browser freaks out (rare, but it happens). :-)

Comment: The problem here still persists - how to tell when the user is (and is not) viewing the page? If the visitor minimizes the page, the ajax will still execute.

Comment: Being realistic, if the browser doesn't respond to gaining/losing focus there's not a lot you can do. However, if it *does* you can simply not carry out the heartbeat. (If you imagine using a timer such as setInterval, simply set a global that you use to control whether the heartbeat is transmitted.) That said, it'll still be a useful relative measure of the time taken to answer a question.

Comment: @Dutchie432: The problem, as I see it, is that there is no way to know if the user is viewing the page anyway. At the very least, maybe the document should be wrapped in a div and the js is listening for the div to be in focus or mouseover, something like that. For instance, if I have the document open but go to open a calculator app to crunch a number, is the document "not open"?

Comment: Exactly. Programming-wise, this is doable, but you really need to ask yourself if you're getting valuable enough data to make it worth your efforts. Ask yourself "How accurate will this be, and more so, how inaccurate COULD it become?" - would this ever be accurate enough that you would be able to act upon a possible "red flag" (or discrepency) in your data and the reported times?

Comment: This is a *very* relative measure anyway (what happens if they spend ten minutes on a phone call when the browser window/div, etc. is focused, etc.). However, being realistic it's probably as good as you're likely to get.

Comment: well my hope was that with a great enough sampling of user claims vs. my collected data, I'd get a variance that would be established over time... thus allowing me to pick record that fall outside the 'normal' variance for further review....

Comment: It's probably ideal for that - at the very least regular offenders should be fairly visible, although you'll need to filter out errant data. (Might not be possible in your scenario but if a user goes to lunch/home for the evening with the browser ticking away...)

Comment: Took the advice offered here - thank you - I've edited the post with code ... and I've got two issues, the most important is that setinterval() doesn't seem to be working consistently...thoughts?

second issue has to do with the ajax call, it's getting a response (the one I'd expect) but it's not logging... if I call the logging page directly, it works fine... do i need to flush something? is something being cached possibly??

Comment: @jpmyob - I'd be tempted to start a new question with the specific issues you're having. (Otherwise this question will become a bit messy.) :-)

Answer (score 1):

window.onfocus and onblur are documented in the MDC, but they're not standards.  Evidently IE has document.onfocusin and .onfocusout :

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

I haven't tried it.  I just read about it here.
http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: Thx Mike, I'm using the information used in this post... appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One somewhat sloppy solution that partially resolves the issue with the browser closing/crashing is to have an ajax function that pings the server DB at a set interval while the document is in focus. This way, if the client crashes, you will be accurate within 30 seconds of how how long the document was open.